Where did the time dependence go in the Jaynes-Cummings Hamiltonian?
In most references the Jaynes-Cummings Hamiltonian is always given as the following form
$$H_{JC} = \omega_0 a^\dagger a + \omega \sigma_z - g(a^\dagger + a)(\sigma_+ + \sigma_-)$$
I notice that the cavity creation and annihilation operators should be time dependent, since the last term comes from the interaction between a quantized EM field and a two level system, namely, $-E \cdot d$.
A quantize EM field typically has the following form
$$E = \sqrt{\frac{\omega_0}{\epsilon_0 V}}(a e^{i(k\cdot r - w_0 t)} + h.c.)$$
so that
$$E\cdot d \propto (a e^{-i\omega_0 t} + a^\dagger e^{i\omega_0 t})(\sigma_+ + \sigma_-)$$
and noticeably there is time dependence in this interaction Hamiltonian.
However, in textbooks (e.g. Steck's Quantum Optics), it seems like they just assume $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are time independent and go on to diagonalize $H_{JC}$ into dressed states. How should I understand the discrepancy?

Shouldn't this be $a^\dagger\sigma_-+a\sigma_+$ in the Jaynes-Cummings-Hamiltonian?

... in which case the keyword is "rotating wave approximation".

@NorbertSchuch the terms you mentioned are indeed from RWA (in the frame defined by $U = \exp(i\omega_0 t \sigma_z)$), where the energy non-conserving terms are dropped. However, if you do that then you would end up with $H = \omega_0 a^{\dagger} a + (\omega - \omega_0) \sigma_z - g(a\sigma_+ + g a^\dagger \sigma_-)$, in which the energy of the two level system is shifted by the cavity frequency. This would not give the familiar JC Hamiltonian.

The expression you gave for the electric field $E$ is the expression for a free field in the Heisenberg picture (or for an interacting field in the Interaction-picture) - that means it already contains the time dependence of the operators.
On the other hand, your expressions for the atomic operators $\sigma_+$ and $\sigma_-$ are time independent: They are clearly Schroedinger-picture operators.
If you want to construct the Hamiltonian, you need to be consistent. Either construct in the Schroedinger Picture, where you will get:
\begin{align}
d \cdot E \propto \sqrt{\frac{\omega_0}{\epsilon_0 V}}(a e^{i(k\cdot r)} + h.c.)(\sigma_+ + \sigma_-)
\end{align}
Or you construct it in the Interaction picture, where it will be
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{\omega_0}{\epsilon_0 V}}(a e^{i(k\cdot r - \omega_0 t)} + h.c.)(\sigma_+ e^{i \omega_{\sigma} t} + h.c.)
\end{align}
Here $\omega_{\sigma}$ is the energy difference of the two level system. Note that the Interaction picture hamiltonian is general time dependent - that is expected - If the Hamiltonian in the Schroedinger picture is time independent, this only dictates that the Heisenberg picture Hamiltonian needs to be time independent.
EDIT: I have written down operators in various pictures, but $a$ and $\sigma$ always mean the same mathematical operator here / always indicate the time independent (Schroedinger-) version of the operator.
As Norbert Schuch has mentioned in a comment, it is however possible to do the "rotating wave approximation", in which one assumes $\omega_{\sigma} \approx \omega_0$ and neglects the terms $a^{\dagger} \sigma_+ e^{i(\omega_0 + \omega_{\sigma}) t} + h.c.$. This approximation can be made in either picture.

Thank you so much for the answer! I see that there is an analogy to the classical field interacting with TLS. In there we just have $H = \omega_{\sigma} \sigma_z - \Omega \cos(\omega_0 t) \sigma_x$, excluding the energy of the field. So this is effectively like the JC Hamiltonian in a frame where the field is Heisenberg and the atom is Schrodinger, and the corresponding Hamiltonian should be $H = \omega_{\sigma} \sigma_z - 2g(a e^{-i\omega_0 t} + a^\dagger e^{i\omega_0 t})\sigma_x$. Everything is now consistent! Thank you! :)

That would be one way to look at it, yes. Nitpick from my side: The field would be Interacting-frame, not Heisenberg.
